# Python + Selenium : Edge extension automation test failing continuously as driver.get(url) is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, behave, edge-chromium

**System :**

- Python
- Behave
- Selenium
- Edge browser
- Target : Extension

**Problem :**
Edge extension automation test is failing continuously. There are multiple observations :

- Page gets loaded with enter manually [Confirmation of URL, other components & factors] but
- driver.get(targeted_goto_url) is not working
- I can see new edge instance but URL is missing

**Solutions I have tried :**

- Chromium property set to `true`
- options.AddExtensionPath(extensions_local_path)
- options.AddExtensions() and passed path of `.crx` file
- Confirmed : Version of EdgeDriver and EdgeHTML should be compatible to each other

Team, Let me know if you have faced and applied working solution for this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working solution**:
I have used `chrome-extension` in targeted URL instead of `extension`